# "sagt man" or "man sagt"

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am just starting my journey to German language, so please excuse me for my trivial question.

What is the difference between "sagt man" and "man sagt". How would I understand where to use right one?

Comment: Do you have a specific context in mind? Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: The other question is with "es gibt" ... just replace "es" with "man" and "gibt" with "sagt"

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this rule yet. I am learning by myself. Danke!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overly simplified:

> Sagt man "X"?

is the word order used to create a question.

> Man sagt "X".

Is a statement.

The first word order is also used in constructions with subordinate clauses

> Wenn man jemanden begrüßen möchte, sagt man "Guten Tag".

Comment: Clarification: VS order *always* used when the vorfeld is already taken - it doesn't have to be taken by a subclause: "In Schottland gibt es Seeungeheuer, sagt man."

Comment: True - also see Emanuels answer in the question he proposed as a duplicate, which has more examples

Answer (score 0):

construction "sagt man" is used when form question with or without "W-Frage".

Example:

```
Sagt man etwas?
```

or

```
Wie sagt man?
```